# How to use functools.partial with os.path.join?

Tags: python, functional-programming, default-arguments, partial-application, functools

Have a list of paths + filenames, all starting with the same `root_dir`. How do I use partial?

#### Attempt

```
from os.path import join as path_join
from functools import partial
from tempfile import gettempdir

root_dir = gettempdir()
root_join = partial(path_join, path=root_dir)
root_join('foo')
```

However this throws an error:

> TypeError: join() got multiple values for keyword argument 'path'

---

Obviously I can write a new function:

```
root_join = lambda root=root_dir, *a: path_join(root_dir, *a)
```

---

However I would like to solve this using `partial`. Any clue how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the keyword argument and it will work:

```
root_join = partial(path_join, root_dir)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> print root_join('foo')
/tmp/foo
```

---

#### Explaination

[`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) takes both keyword arguments and positional arguments to be passed on to the wrapped function, these are combined with the arguments passed when the resulting partial function is called, so:

```
partial_func = partial(func, positional_1, positional_2, keyword_1='A', keyword_2='B')
partial_func(positional_3, keywork_2='B')
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
func(positional_1, positional_2, positional_3, keyword_1='A', keyword_2='B')
```

Note that positional arguments are combined in order, the ones from partial first, then the ones supplied at call time.  As always they also come before keyword arguments.

This means your code:

```
root_join = partial(path_join, path=root_dir)
root_join('foo')
```

Was equivalent to:

`path_join('foo', path=root_dir)`

Here, 'foo' is given as the `path` argument to [`os.path.join(path, *p)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) positionally, and then there is an attempt to assign `path` as a keyword argument as well.

Comment: xD, that was simple. Not sure why I thought `partial` only worked with keyword args…

Answer (score 2):

According to [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)'s definition, the name of first argument for `os.path.join()` is `path`. So supplying `path` parameter as named keyword argument via `functools.partial` generates an attempt of passing multiple values on same key.

Since `functools.partial()` also supports supplying of positional argument, you can try this:

```
>>> import functools
>>> import os.path
>>> root_join = functools.partial(os.path.join, 'root')
>>> root_join('path/to/somewhere')
'root/path/to/somewhere'
```